# Limit Content Length at URL Level in for iis or on asp project

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have seen how to set length using `web.config` such as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- ~ 2GB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- ~ 4GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can this be set at the url level?

`/Login.aspx` to have a different length than the default one.

Edit

Upon searching l found this [here](https://www.netscout.com/what-is-ddos/slow-post-attacks) which specified Set tighter URL-specific limits for every resource that accepts a message header and body.

Comment: You can not set the url level content length

This is the security reason

Check this link here is the full details 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Comment: I don't recommend you to use url level. If you want to set the Content Length, then you can also set it in iis. double click Request Filtering and on the rightest panel click Edit Feature Settings. In Request Limits section you can set the maxAllowedContentLength.